# UseGoogleAuthentication generates error cannot convert lambda expression to type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have looked in many examples in msdn website, stackoverflow and ... and everywhere google authentication is added like below:

```
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.ClientId = "CLIENTID";
        options.ClientSecret = "CLIENTSECRET";
    });
```

but in my code, the whole block is underlined with red error indication giving the error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'GoogleOptions' because it is not a delegate type

What can be wrong?
I'm using Asp.NET MVC .NetCore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install nuget if not installed already **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google** and change your googleoptions below.

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    ClientId = Configuration["ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = Configuration["ClientSecret"]
});
```